# Change Highcharts title dynamically in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm actually trying to change dynamically a Highcharts title in an Angular project. I'd like to change the title when I select an option in a ng-select and when an option is selected, the chart gets that value and replace the title with. But I'm having some difficulties to find what's not working correctly. I've tried multiple things like inputs and outputs to get the value (which is in the parent component) and put it in my chart (in a child component) but I think that I'm missing something. I put my HTML and TS from my child and parent components below, hoping that somebody can help me to find a solution to my problem :

**Child TS :**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-column-graph',
  templateUrl: './column-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./column-graph.component.scss']
})
export class ColumnGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  btn: any
  //Output pour modifier le titre du graphique dynamiquement
  @Output() titreEvent: EventEmitter<Highcharts.Chart> = new EventEmitter<Highcharts.Chart>()

  @Input() titreGraphique!: string
  //Input pour récupérer les données du parent (IndexComponent)
  @Input() data: any = {
    "Patient": [
        ['Patient 1', 0],
        ['Patient 2', 0],
        ['Patient 3', 0],
        ['Patient 4', 46]
    ]
};

  patients: any = [{
    name: 'Patient 1',
    color: 'rgb(201, 36, 39)'
}, {
    name: 'Patient 2',
    color: 'rgb(201, 36, 39)'
}, {
    name: 'Patient 3',
    color: 'rgb(0, 82, 180)'
}, {
    name: 'Patient 4',
    color: 'rgb(215, 0, 38)'
}];

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor: string = 'chart';
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
                                      title: {text: this.titreGraphique},
                                      credits: {enabled: false},
                                      series: [{
                                      data: [1, 2, 3],
                                      type: 'column'
                                  }] };
  updateFlag: boolean = true;
  oneToOneFlag: boolean = true;
  runOutsideAngular: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

  setTitreGraphique() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({title: {text: this.titreGraphique}})
  }
}
```

**Child HTML :**

```
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"

  [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
  [options]="chartOptions"

  [(update)]="updateFlag"
  [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag"
  [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngular"
  
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

**Parent TS :**

```
import { Chart } from 'highcharts';
import { Patient } from 'src/app/models/patient.model';
import { PatientService } from 'src/app/services/patient.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() donnees!: any
  //Chaîne de caractères représentant le type de données sélectionné
  typeDonneeSelectionne: string = "Bonjour"

  //Tableau de patients utilisé plus tard dans la fonction subscribe()
  peoples!: Patient[]

  //Type de données à choisir dans un ng-select
  typeDonnees = ["Assuétudes", "Biométrie", "Constantes biologiques", "Paramètres"]

  //Variable booléenne décidant de l'activation des ng-select des patients
  disablePatients!: boolean

  //Injection du service de patients dans le constructeur
  constructor(private _patientService: PatientService) { 
    //Désactivation des ng-select des patients (activation lors de la détection d'un changement dans le ng-select concerné)
    this.disablePatients = true
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Obtenir tous les patients
    this._patientService.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        //Récupérer tous les patients et les mettre dans un tableau de patients
        this.peoples = data
        //Mapping permettant le fonctionnement correct de la recherche dans les ng-select
        this.peoples.map(p => {
          p.nomPrenom = `${p.admin.prenom} ${p.admin.nom}`
        })
      },
      //Dans le cas d'une erreur...
      error => {
        console.log("Erreur lors du mapping prénom + nom : " + error);
      }
    )
  }

  //Fonction pour obtenir un patient via son ID
  getPatientById(item: any): void {
    //Si l'objet récupéré est trouvé...
    if (item != undefined)
    {
      //Récupérer le patient par l'ID de l'objet récupéré
      this._patientService.getById(item.id).subscribe(p => console.log(p))
    }
  }
  //Fonction pour activer les ng-select des patients une fois que l'on a choisi un type de données à afficher
  enablePatients(item: any): void {
    //Si l'object récupéré n'est pas vide...
    if (item != undefined)
    {
      //...On attribue sa valeur à la variable "typeDonneeSelectionne" via une méthode...
      this.setTypeSelectionne(item)
      //...et on désactive les les ng-select des patients.
      this.disablePatients = false
    }

  }
  //Fonction pour changer le titre du graphique dynamiquement
  setTitreGraphique(chart: Chart) {
    chart.options = {title: {text: this.typeDonneeSelectionne}}
  }
  //
  setTypeSelectionne(item: any) {
    this.typeDonneeSelectionne = item
  }
  //Fonction d'envoi des données au graphique
  sendDataToGraph(patient: Patient): void {
    switch(this.typeDonneeSelectionne)
    {
      case "Assuétudes": this.donnees = patient.assuetudes;break;
      case "Biométrie": this.donnees = patient.biometrie;break;
      case "Constantes biologiques": this.donnees = patient.constBiologique;break;
      case "Paramètres": this.donnees = patient.parametres;break;
      default: console.log("Erreur détectée !");break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Parent HTML :**

```
    <h3>Type de données : </h3>
    <ng-select class="customSelect"
            [items]="typeDonnees"
            autofocus
            [clearable]="false"
            [searchable]="false"
            (change)="enablePatients($event); setTitreGraphique($event)"
            #typeDonneesSelect></ng-select>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <h3>Premier patient : </h3>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h3>Deuxième patient : </h3>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h3>Troisième patient : </h3>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h3>Quatrième patient : </h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <td>
        <ng-select class="custom"
        [items]="peoples"
        bindLabel="nomPrenom"
        bindValue="id"
        (change)="getPatientById($event)"
        [readonly]="disablePatients">
            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ng-select class="custom"
        [items]="peoples"
        bindLabel="nomPrenom"
        bindValue="id"
        (change)="getPatientById($event)"
        [readonly]="disablePatients">
            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ng-select class="custom"
        [items]="peoples"
        bindLabel="nomPrenom"
        bindValue="id"
        (change)="getPatientById($event)"
        [readonly]="disablePatients">
            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ng-select class="custom"
        [items]="peoples"
        bindLabel="nomPrenom"
        bindValue="id"
        (change)="getPatientById($event)"
        [readonly]="disablePatients">
            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
                <span>{{ item.admin.prenom + ' ' + item.admin.nom }}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-select>
    </td>
</table>

<app-column-graph [data]="donnees" (titreEvent)="setTitreGraphique($event)"></app-column-graph>
```

If you need more informations, feel free to ask me. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @bindash, Your code seems to be incomplete. Could you create a full working example in some online code editor? You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-pndysg?file=src%2Fapp%2FchartsContainer%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @ppotaczek Don't worry, I've finally succeed to change my title. Thank you anyway. How can I mark this thread as resolved ? I'm not using StackOverflow often, sorry.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: @bindash can you please post your solution on how to change the title dynamically?